# Is Risch algorithm learnable by a human being?

Tags: calculus, algorithms

I've discovered a few months ago about the Risch's algorithm. It seems to be the best thing we have to find antiderivatives. Some days ago, I've found lectures on the integration of elementary functions. And in the abstract of the lectures, the author argued that there is a misconception among calculus professors: That they say that derivation is just an algorithm, but integration is not and he wants to show that it's not completely true. In his lectures, he gives:

- Hermite algorithm.
- Lazard-Rioboo-Trager algorithm.
- Abel's theorem and the non-integrability of algebraic functions in terms of elementary functions.

So, it seems that these algoritms are learnable and also that learn it would not be so overkill. I got curious if Risch algorithm could also be learned by a human being.

Comment: There may be a misunderstanding by your unnamed "author" here.  The Risch decision procedure applied to general elementary functions is not fully an algorithm because it requires a determination of whether certain intermediate computations result exactly in zero, a step for which there is no known effective algorithm.  Perhaps this seemingly small gap can be filled in, but at present it might be best to refer instead to the [Risch semi-algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm#Decidability).